# Прозрачность для элемента, а не его содержимого

Tags: c#, wpf

Собственно вопрос - "Как сделать прозрачность для элемента так, что-бы его содержимое оставалось видимым?"

Например - нам нужно написать красивый текст в рамочке.

```
<Border x:Name="BRD" Background="Red" CornerRadius="5">
   <Label>Наш прекрасный текст</Label>
</Border>
```

Красиво? Не очень, но нам нужно сделать `Border` полупрозрачным, однако так, что-бы текст оставался непрозрачным полностью. Можно это сделать вот так -

```
<Grid>
    <Border x:Name="BRD" Background="Red" CornerRadius="5"
            Height="{Binding ElementName=MyLabel, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="..."></Border>
    <Label x:Name="MyLabel">Наш прекрасный текст</Label>
</Grid>
```

Но это можно сделать если объект один, а если их много. Или мы, например, хотим еще сюда картику к тексту, а это все и еще одну полупрозрачную рамочку...

В общем - пытаюсь найти какое-нибудь унифицированное решение для этих целей.

---

P.S. Проблема не только в цвете, который можно сделать полупрозрачным - я ищу решение для вообще любого элемента, а не только для тех, кто полностью описывается цветом.

Comment: Приведите код для воспроизведения проблемы

Comment: Что то не понял, чем второй вариант не понравился. Делаете Grid, внутрь помещаете border со своими параметрами и рядом (не в border) помещаете другие компоненты (например еще один Grid со своей разметкой). Вы получите прозрачный Border с не прозрачными элементами на нем.

Comment: Второй вариант — ваш, развивайте его, более простого решения не будет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ один элемент там можно сделать, ну два. К десятому код превращается в шляпу с кашей, а верстальщик банально устаёт. 
Печально, что него лучшего метода.

Comment: Почему? Вам же не под каждый Lable надо делать Border. Тут Border играет некий "Задний фон" для Grid'a, а что внутри грида, это уже стандартная разметка. То есть достаточно 1 Border'a внутри Grid'a, почему "каша" мне не понятно, может приведете пример этой "каши" ?

Comment: Ну возможно вы и правы, ибо пример так сходу я не приведу.

Comment: А если вас вообще эта строка напрягает, то сделайте свой контрол и оберните нужный контент в него, тогда будет всего 1 строка, по типу `<ctr:MyBorder Opacity=".4" Background="Red">Ваш контент<ctr:MyBorder>`. Так что лично я считаю, что вы пытаетесь изобрести велосипед, почему - нам не рассказываете.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.button1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
```

На примере настройки для кнопки,  либо через панель свойств.

Comment: Вы нечего не перепутали?

Comment: Нет. Фон кнопки будет прозрачный, а если добавить текст на кнопку, то он будет виден. Что по вашему мнению я перепутал?

Comment: Ну во первых, вопрос по WPF, во вторых в WPF используется XAML, а в  третьих, в WPF нет `BackColor` и `FlatStyle`.

Comment: Прошу прощения, так как плохой интернет, у меня прогрузился только первый абзац вопроса. Не уловил сути. Поэтому попал в такую ситуацию.